# Are jfieldID and jmethodID bound to the specific class or can I use them on subclass objects?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

When I calculate a field ID (or method ID) with `env->GetFieldID(superClass, name, descriptor`) (or `env->GetMethodID(superClass, method, descriptor)`), can I use the same ID on objects of type `subClass` (which inherits from `superClass`)?

Comment: Certainly not the fieldID,  not sure about the methodID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but if the derived class overrides a method, it will introduce a new ID.

With a `superID` calculated for super-class, you will be effectively calling

```
obj.super.method()
```

You can consider it as an analog of `Java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod()` and `Java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields()`.

Comment: So I can think of  jfieldIDs as offsets in objects and jmethodIDs as fixed memory addresses rather than offsets in vtables?

Comment: The `typedef`s for `jmethodID` and `jfieldID` are, as I recall, of the form `struct foo *`, for what it is worth.

Comment: @S1lentSt0rm: I would rather think about them in terms of `Java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod()` and `Java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields()`